# Вывод значений массива, который является массивом другого массива в PHP

Tags: php, массивы

Имеется задача которую, я не могу решить гуглением, курением манов, и копипастингом. Так как довольно сложно задавать вопрос, как впрочем и гуглить, незная базовой терминологии, но начну с предыстории. Если же нет, смотрите сразу суть вопроса.

**Предыстория:** Искал доступные методы для работы с MPD (Music Player Deamon) нашел несколько php-классов на гитхаб, [один из них](https://github.com/bobwallis/phpMPD) оказался даже рабочим.
Мучая класс я сделал из него json, и всякое другое. Но то количество данных которые он выдает для меня много, и я пытаясь вывести из них только часть, целый день натыкаюсь на костыли и неработающие решения.

**Суть вопроса:** При использвании выше указанного класса я вывожу массив:

```
print_r ($mpd->currentsong());
```

Если выводить просто `print_r ($mpd);` то это тоже массив.
И я никак немогу понять каким образом, мне вывести только часть этих данных которые выводит массив. К примеру только Title и Artist
Пример массива currentsong:

```
Array ( [file] => Cien/2010 - Anti Humanity (Demo)/03. Glory and Salvation.mp3 [Last-Modified] => 2018-09-18T17:32:24Z [Time] => 347 [Artist] => Cieñ [Title] => Glory and salvation [Album] => Anti humanity [Track] => 3 [Pos] => 261 [Id] => 261 )
```

Пытался и квадратными скобками выводить значения, и резать array_slice, где-то не работает, где-то ужасные костыли. Есть ли вообще возможность сделать решение более элегантным и быстрым способом? И пардоньте за многословие, если что поправлю чего не вписал и доплню и исправлю. Помогите пожалуйста найти решение.

**Вопрос решен благодаря помощи:** @teran @lets-say-pie

Comment: `print_r($mpd->currentsong()['Artist']);` не работает?

Comment: `$x = array_intersect_key($song, array_flip(['title', 'artist'])`. но если вам надо просто вывести нужное, дак выводите. зачем печатать весь массив то

Comment: Let's say Pie, работает. А в вашем решении возможно в одном принте вывести два значения, и артиста и тайтл? Это было бы самым идеальным вариантом, но не понимая синтаксиса, это кажется нереальным... А делать два запроса к $mpd продублировав сторку нежалательно. Впрочем если это невозможно, ваш ответ меня устраивает более чем.

Comment: @SergeyKrueger, как предложил @teran, можно так: `$x = array_intersect_key($mpd->currentsong(), array_flip(['Artist', 'Title']); print_r($x);`

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ',' or ')'

Comment: Скобка пропущена в конце 
`$x = array_intersect_key($mpd->currentsong(), array_flip(['Artist', 'Title'])); print_r($x);`